# How can I find eagerly created beans in Application Context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

I'm studying Spring IoC and I would like to raise a question.

How can I view in ApplicationContext all created singletons?

Since they are creating eagerly does it mean that they must exist in the container before .getBean() method is invoked on it?

I mean bot only `BeanDefinitions` but fully instantiated, initialized instances.

Comment: Have a look at the `ListableBeanFactory` interface. Most ApplicationContexts implement it.